# How can I make a crosshair effect on a cursor on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't really know how to explain what I want but a prime example is slipknot1.com/home, where they have put in a crosshair that follows the cursor and covers the full screen. If anyone can help that could be great

Comment: You'll need to figure out how to use something like this: https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Comment: Please provide at least a minimal example of what you've already tried on yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Check this if it helps.

```js
var cH = $('#crosshair-h'),
    cV = $('#crosshair-v');

$(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
    cH.css('top',e.pageY);
    cV.css('left',e.pageX);
});
```

```css
#crosshair-h{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
#crosshair-v{
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.hair{    
    position: fixed;
    border: 0.02px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="crosshair-h" class="hair"></div>
<div id="crosshair-v" class="hair"></div>
```